# How do I combine disabled days using react-day-picker-input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-day-picker

I am using the NPM package `react-day-picker` and there seems to be minimal documentation on the `react-day-picker-input` element. It mentions a prop called `dayPickerProps` which takes an object called `disabledDays`. I can't figure out how to disable weekends and specific days combined. I got it to disable weekends and the days individually but when combined only the first is taken. The documentation discusses how to implement this for the regular day picker but not the day picker input component which takes different props. Does anyone familiar with this package know how I can accomplish this task?

Heres my [Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/lx2lp1x1m7)

Notice how removing the `before` key enables the `daysOfWeek` key to work.
Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this instead

```
dayPickerProps={{
      modifiers: {
        disabled: [
          {
            daysOfWeek: [0, 6]
          },
          {
            before: new Date(2018, 7, 8)
          }
        ]
      }
    }}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/537qkxy4wn

Answer (score 1):

If you only use DayPicker, you can just pass modifiers as props like this

```
<DayPicker
  modifiers={{
    disabled: [
      {
        daysOfWeek: [0, 6]
      },
      {
        before: today
      }
    ]
  }}
/>
```